# how to make autocomplete work in mvc with Different layers

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc

My view is this [image: LeaveDetail]

The project has Different business layers. I am focused on two layers Controller And Repository Layer. 
Controller has the logic and it gives direction to master repository where data is altered. every logic is achieved by making stored procedure. 
I want to create autocomplete feature for Employee Name By taking data from Employee table but by stored procedure. I created one SP . Obviously its wrong but take a look at it

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[EmployeeSuggestion]
@FirstName Varchar(50)
As
Begin
Select FirstName from Employee WHERE
  --    FirstName = @FirstName and
     (ISNULL(@FirstName,'')='' OR Employee.FirstName LIKE '%'+@FirstName+'%')
end
--exec EmployeeSuggestion 'shaili'
```

My LeaveModel is defined like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Synoverge.Component.ExcelHelper;

namespace Synoverge.InternalApps.Model.Master
{
    public class LeaveModel: BaseModel
    {
        //public LeaveModel()
        //{
        //    Suggestion = new List<LeaveModel>();
        //}
        //List<LeaveModel> Suggestion { get; set; }
        public String EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string ReportingManagerName { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int EmoplyeeId { get; set; }
        public int ReportingManagerId { get; set; }
        public DateTime LeaveFromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime LeaveToDate { get; set; }
        public string Remark { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My LeaveController

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Synoverge.InternalApps.Web.Common;
using Synoverge.InternalApps.Common;

namespace Synoverge.InternalApps.Web.Controllers
{
    public partial class MasterController : BaseController
    {
        //
        // GET: /Leave/

        public ActionResult LeaveDetail()
        {
            LeaveModel leaveModel = new LeaveModel();
            //leaveModel.EmployeeName = masterRepository.Suggestion();
            return View(leaveModel);
        }
    }
}
```

My MasterRepository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data;
using Synoverge.InternalApps.Model;
using Synoverge.InternalApps.Model.Master;
using Synoverge.InternalApps.Model.ExcelExport;


namespace Synoverge.InternalApps.Repository
{
    public class MasterRepository : BaseRepository
    {
        #region Leave

        //public List<LeaveModel> Suggestion()
        //{
        //    List<LeaveModel> SugInfo = new List<LeaveModel>();
        //    SugInfo = this.DB.ExecuteSprocAccessor<LeaveModel>("dbo.[EmployeeSuggestion]").ToList();
        //        return SugInfo;
        //}




        #endregion
```

I think You guys will understand how this application working now. every main stuff is in Master repository. now I tried to create auto complete on it but i am nor succesful and I have no ideas of how to do it too. i Searched net and they all teach me in controller method and with no stored procedure. please help me i want a solution for this. how should be its stored procedure and what to code in controller and MasterRepository. I also want to know Logic of creating different business layer. Does it changes the logic we apply too.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok thanks.